# Regex match omitting first character in search

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Haven't written JavaScript in a while so it's probably a very obvious mistake.

using RegExp.match(..) in JavaScript, it's not picking up/ skipping the first character in the strings being searched for. Below is the output from a list of strings:

```
*query = 'g'*

Genetic engineering:    g,g
Gene therapy:   null
Surfactant: null
Human cloning:  g
Protein production: null
Microfluidics:  null
Polymerase chain reaction:  null
RNA:    null
Restriction enzyme: null
Picotechnology: g
Femtotechnology:    g
Grey goo:   g
Molecular engineering:  g,g
Microfluidics:  null
Molecular nanotechnology:   g
Nanoengineering:    g,g
Atom probe: null
Maxwell's demon:    null
```

So for example, 'Genetic engineering' should be: g,g,g but the first (,and only the first,) character is omitted. If I typed 'enetic' for example then genetic engineering will match successfully.

Here is the code:

```
function createFilterFor(query) {
           return function filterFn(state) {
             let re = new RegExp(query, 'g');
             console.log(state+":\t"+state.match(re,'ig'))
             return (state.match(re,'ig') != null? true : false );
           };
        }
```

This function returns a list of items for a search text field like so:

```
(8) ["Genetic engineering", "Human cloning", "Picotechnology", "Femtotechnology", "Grey goo", "Molecular engineering", "Molecular nanotechnology", "Nanoengineering"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have simple typo, missing the 'i' flag:

```
let re = new RegExp(query, 'ig');
```

So your Regex only find lowercase letters.

Comment: *places forehead on palms* .. Can't believe I missed that - thanks!